# How do I compile with zlib on windows using gcc?

Tags: c, windows, gcc, mingw, zlib

My aim is to compile zlib alongside my application files, I use gcc from tdm-gcc and have cloned the repository https://github.com/madler/zlib

in */example* there is a *zpipe.c* file which utilizes the library but I can't seem to get it compiling on windows.

I've added *-lz* to the end of my compile command and I receive `/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lz` error.

If I try to compile with just *-Izlib* I end up with these errors:

```
$ gcc -Izlib zpipe.c -o zpipe
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjXicsi.o:zpipe.c:(.text+0x6a): undefined reference to `deflateInit_'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjXicsi.o:zpipe.c:(.text+0xca): undefined reference to `deflateEnd'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjXicsi.o:zpipe.c:(.text+0x12e): undefined reference to `deflate'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjXicsi.o:zpipe.c:(.text+0x1be): undefined reference to `deflateEnd'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjXicsi.o:zpipe.c:(.text+0x23c): undefined reference to `deflateEnd'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjXicsi.o:zpipe.c:(.text+0x2c0): undefined reference to `inflateInit_'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjXicsi.o:zpipe.c:(.text+0x320): undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjXicsi.o:zpipe.c:(.text+0x36f): undefined reference to `inflate'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjXicsi.o:zpipe.c:(.text+0x3d1): undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjXicsi.o:zpipe.c:(.text+0x440): undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjXicsi.o:zpipe.c:(.text+0x474): undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! I've searched stack overflow and tried all the suggestions and also googled and I'm still having issues.

*The errors seem trivial and I've fixed such errors in the past, but this one I'm stuck on and I'm not sure what else to try.*

Comment: If libz has not been installed to the standard library search path, you will need to add the `-L libpath` option to the command.

Comment: You're not linking to the zlib library, `-Izlib` is not enough. You probably need something like: `gcc -Izlib -Lzlib zpipe.c -o zpipe`

Comment: @IanAbbott still fails, with the multiple errors messages. I used `gcc -Izlib -Lzlib zpipe.c -o zpipe`

Comment: @Jabberwocky Didn't make a difference, I've also tried uninstalling tdm-gcc and trying again, the aim is to have this code portable to also compile on linux, but for now I just want to get it running on windows to understand how inflate and deflate work.

Comment: How did you build and install zlib?

Comment: @IanAbbott I haven't built it as a library or anything, I'm trying to compile the example file zpipe.c using just gcc and linking with the source files I pulled down from git

Comment: The `-lz` option tells it to link to the `libz` library - that's either a DLL or a static library. So it you haven't built it, it won't link. If you do not want to link to the library, you could probably compile the zlib source files into the program directly, but that is not the normal way to do it, so you are on your own there.

Comment: @IanAbbott When I pass `-Izlib` and `-Lzlib` and use `#include "zlib.h"` it compiles fine, but that's if I have nothing in main, the moment I use any of those functions in my post, it fails. Any idea why?

Comment: `#include "zlib.h"` only *declares* the Zlib functions. The Zlib functions are *defined* by the Zlib \*.c files, so you need to compile the .c files that define the functions you are calling. The \*.c files are normally compiled into the libz library that can be linked with your application code.

Comment: @IanAbbott Yeah, check my answer below :) I made a little tutorial for it. I got it working. cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1) Creating the static library.

Inside the zlib folder where the *.c* and *.h* files are located running `gcc -c *.c` will generate *.o* files that can be used to build the library.

after you have the *.o* files, running `ar -rc libz.a *.o` will generate a *libz.a* file, this will allow you to link via `-lz`

### 2) Compiling zpipe.c into zpipe.exe

put *zpipe.c* into the folder where libz.a is located, this is for simplicity when compiling.

running `gcc -L. zpipe.c -o zpipe.exe -lz` will create *zpipe.exe*.

### 3) Quick demo

Create a file *hello.txt* with `Hello World!` inside.

Run `./zpipe.exe < hello.txt > output.txt` this will inflate the data in *hello.txt* and put it in *output.txt*

Run `./zpipe.exe -d < output.txt > original.txt` to decompress the file and you will see *Hello World!* inside *original.txt*

#### Definitions

`-L.` tells gcc to use the current folder for the header files.

`-lz` tells gcc to compile with a static library who's name starts with *lib* and ends in *.a* for eg. *libexample.a* would be *-lexample*

Comment: It would be easier to use `make` to build the library.

Comment: @IanAbbott I have a make file and will bootstrap something together at a later time, right now I don't care about the small nuances and just want to compile this library to see if it even has what I need and works how I need it to.

The tutorial is to get your feet off the ground at least and understand how to compile zlib manually. There is no documentation on the internet that explains how to build it just a lot of comments saying `-lz` you need to use `-lz` but they never explain that you need to build it and link it and what that manual process looks like.

Comment: I suppose the clue is in the name Zlib. It is a library and so is intended to be built and installed as a library. There are other projects that use similar code (inflate/deflate algorithm), but do not use Zlib or the Zlib stream format. For example GNU Gzip and Info-ZIP. (Zlib was originally a spin-off from the Info-ZIP project.) Still, your technique may be useful to someone.

Comment: @IanAbbott Very fair comments,I think perhaps I was a little stubborn and assumed I only needed to specify where the .h and .c files were and the program would compile.

I don't build and/or use external libraries often so my knowledge of how they work is pretty minimal but I got it to work in the end and have included all the required files in my project.

Thanks for all the extra info, much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

When using [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) shell it's quite simple, just run the following commands (replace `/usr/local` with the desired location):

```sh
INSTALLPREFIX=/usr/local
wget -c http://www.zlib.net/zlib-1.2.12.tar.gz
tar xfz zlib-1.2.12.tar.gz
cd zlib-1.2.12
make -f win32/Makefile.gcc install \
 SHARED_MODE=1 \
 INCLUDE_PATH=$INSTALLPREFIX/include \
 LIBRARY_PATH=$INSTALLPREFIX/lib \
 BINARY_PATH=$INSTALLPREFIX/bin
```